# Count of a specific word from the entire website in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, logic, bs4dash

I need to find the matches of a WORD from the entire website, for example:

Find all the words "tutorial" in the web https://www.w3schools.com/

I tried the following Python code but it returns me the count of home pages and its dropdown tabs "tutorial" counts only, I want to get the count of "tutorial" from the entire website, i.e. if taken to another page of the same website it should count the word tutorial from there also.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
page = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
solo_body = soup.body
body = solo_body.text.lower()
train_count = (body.count("tutorial"))
print(train_count)
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible. A page is loaded in the browser only when you go to it. So even if a website has multiple pages, it is not loaded until you go to it. And even then you only get the count of occurences in the code not the webpage. i.e a word maybe in code but not displayed. You are pulling html content which has code. You can only get info based on that.

Comment: If possible can you help me with that? @leoOrion

Comment: @Sufiyan-Ghori can you help?

Comment: Its not possible though....